# loop array values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Here I access 'date' key values from rows of DB table. And I can echo these values, no problem.

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM alfred ORDER BY id ASC");
$row = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($row as $key => $value){
    $availDate = $value['date'];
    echo $availDate.'<br />';
}
```

This loop above shows all 'date' values from DB, in this case there are 3 dates- "2012-09-25" "2012-09-27" and "2012-09-29".
But then I need to compare each of these 'date' values against values of `$date->format('Y-m-d')` from the code below and display each date with corresponding "busy" or "available" status into separate `<td>` of the table. My following version compares only the "last" value of 'date' key - "2012-09-29", but I need to compare each 'date' value from the array above, it means also "2012-09-25" and "2012-09-27". I have tried many versions but still unsuccessful. Any ideas?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$endDate = new DateTime('+10 day');
for($date->format('Y-m-d'); $date->format('Y-m-d') < $endDate->format('Y-m-d'); $date->modify('+1 day')){
    if ($date->format('Y-m-d') == $availDate){
    echo '<td>'.$date->format('Y-m-d/D').' busy</td>';
    }   else {
        echo '<td>'.$date->format('Y-m-d/D').' available</td>';
        }
}
```

Here is the result I am getting now:

```
2012-09-21/Fri available 2012-09-22/Sat available 2012-09-23/Sun available 2012-09-24/Mon available 2012-09-25/Tue available 2012-09-26/Wed available 2012-09-27/Thu available 2012-09-28/Fri available 2012-09-29/Sat busy 2012-09-30/Sun available
```

But in fact I need to show "busy" status also into `<td>` of "2012-09-25" and `<td>` of "2012-09-27" as these also are 'date' values that are existing in $row array. Unfortunately I can not post any images here to show, but I hope my result above gives you the idea.

SOLVED with the help of in_array below:

```
$aAvailDate = array();
foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        $aAvailDate[] = $value['date'];
}
$date = new DateTime();
    $endDate = new DateTime('+10 day');
    for($date->format('Y-m-d'); $date->format('Y-m-d') < $endDate->format('Y-m-d'); $date->modify('+1 day')){
        if (in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $aAvailDate)){
        echo '<td>'.$date->format('Y-m-d/D').' busy</td>';
        }     else {
            echo '<td>'.$date->format('Y-m-d/D').' available</td>';
            }
    }
```

Comment: Although your Question is Unclear but AFAIK 
you want to display "Busy" if available date occurs between given date and you want to check upto 3 weeks. Am i Right?

Comment: Would it not be easier to do the date check in your SQL?

Comment: @raivis : try with MySQL solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a forum. It's a Q&A site. You shouldn't post the answer inside the question and yell SOLVED in title. You should instead post the answer as an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, but I think you are running [`->format('Y-m-d')`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) unnecessarily here, and this is messing up your logic.

Every time you run that, PHP is turning your object into a string, which you are then comparing against other strings. This won't do anything useful.

Instead, you should be using the features of [the `DateTime` class](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to compare the objects themselves. The only time you should need to use the `format()` method is when outputting to the browser, into an SQL query, etc

Comment: 'date' values that I get from DB are stored like ('Y-m-d') thats why I turn $date into this format

Comment: You should convert the other way: turn your strings into objects, not your objects into strings.

Answer (score 0):

Although your Question is Unclear but AFAIK

you want to display "Busy" if available date occurs between given date upto 3 Weeks 
otherwise display "free"

I would like to suggest you to do this with MySQL (Not tested)

```
SELECT *,
IF( `DateCol` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 WEEK), 'Busy','Free') 
AS status
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `while` loop instead of a `foreach`.  Also, compare the DateTime objects directly, not the formatted strings.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$endDate = new DateTime('+3 week');

while( $date < $endDate) {
    if ($date->format('Y-m-d') == $availDate){
        echo '<td class="busy">busy</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>free</td>';
    }
    $date->modify("+1 day");
}
```

Comment: Rather than just posting the corrected code, can you include a comment explaining what you have changed?

Comment: @raivis Just updated with a new solution. Also dded some explanatory text

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (If I understand what you're trying to do correctly)

```
<?php

$avail_dates = array();
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS availDate FROM alfred ORDER BY id ASC"); 
$row = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
foreach ($row as $key => $value){ 
$avail_dates[] = $value['availDate']; 
}


$startDate = date('Y-m-d');
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate)) . " +3 week"));
?>

<table>
<?php
foreach ($avail_dates as $availDate){

echo "<tr><td>$availDate</td>";

if (($startDate <= $availDate) && ($endDate >= $availDate)){
echo "<td class='busy'>busy</td>"; 
}else{
echo "<td>free</td>"; 
}

echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Instead of printing values, I would add them to the array, and then run a loop on that array, comparing the values to the given start and end dates. I also wouldn't fetch all from the table if you nly need a date.

Answer (score -1):

May be like this?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$endDate = new DateTime('+3 week');
for($date->format('Y-m-d'); $date->format('Y-m-d') < $endDate->format('Y-m-d'); $date->modify('+1 day')){
    $tempDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    if ($tempDate === $availDate){
    echo '<td class="busy">busy</td>';
    } else {
      echo '<td>free</td>';
        }
}
```

Comment: what difference will strict comparison (`===` ) make?

Comment: nop. this version again checks only the "last" value of 'date' keys

Comment: @diEcho '===' makes no difference as all these values are same datatype also

Comment: I'm voting this answer down not just because it doesn't fix the problem, but because pasting the entire code with a one-character change is not a good way of explaining a solution.